# Aggregating on elastic search on dictionary of json

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I need some assistance on elasic search
I have this json

```
{
    "serials":{ "pack":"123", "asset":"123", "brand":"123"}
}
```

and my document when saved in elastic search shows this

```
serials
 asset : string
 brand : string
 pack : string
```

so I need to aggregate on assets. I tried this but getting nothing in aggregation

```
{
    "size" : 0,
    "aggs" : { 
        "eventNames" : { 
            "terms" : { 
              "field" : "serials.asset"
            }
        }
    }
}
```